# Replace XComment with its Contents

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

Within a valid XML file, I have the following section:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <WorkingDir>C:\SomeFolder\</WorkingDir>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <Files Include="$(WorkingDir)**\*.txt" />
  <!--<Files Include="$(WorkingDir)**\*.log" />-->
  <Files Include="$(WorkingDir)**\*.bat" />
  <!--<Files Include="$(WorkingDir)**\*.ps1" />
  <Files Include="$(WorkingDir)**\*.psm" />-->
  <Files Include="$(WorkingDir)**\*.cmd" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I load it using XDocument, and can then retrieve the list of comments by using XComment - but assume I only want the first one:

```
var xComment = (doc.Elements().DescendantNodes().OfType<XComment>().First();
```

I now want to replace this comment with its actual content:

```
xComment.ReplaceWith(xComment.Value);
```

However, this is what I get as output:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <WorkingDir>C:\SomeFolder\</WorkingDir>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <Files Include="$(WorkingDir)**\*.txt" />
  &lt;Files Include="$(WorkingDir)**\*.log" /&gt;
  <Files Include="$(WorkingDir)**\*.bat" />
  <!--<Files Include="$(WorkingDir)**\*.ps1" />
  <Files Include="$(WorkingDir)**\*.psm" />-->
  <Files Include="$(WorkingDir)**\*.cmd" />
</ItemGroup>
```

If I output the contents of `xComment.Value` separately (using `Console.WriteLine()`, for example), I get `<Files Include="$(WorkingDir)**\*.log" />` - so what happens to the angle brackets  when I use `XNode.ReplaceWith()`? How do ensure that the character formatting is preserved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you need to parse the XML in the comment first i.e. `xComment.ReplaceWith(XElement.Parse(xComment.Value))`. That should work as long as the comment contains the markup of a single element node, as is the case for the first comment in your sample. In a more general case (i.e. when the comment contains markup for more than one element or other for other nodes) you need `xComment.ReplaceWith(XElement.Parse("<dummy>" + xComment.Value + "</dummy>").Nodes())`.